# Specific examples of "NP" problems becoming a "P" problem?

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity

I was watching this YouTube video on "P vs NP" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YX40hbAHx3s .

In this video, they mention how some problems that were originally thought to be NP - a "trick" was then discovered such that these problems could be reclassified as P.

I tried searching online for concrete examples of this - for example, some **specific** math/computer problems which were NP and the precise "trick" that was discovered to make them as P.

But I don't think I was correctly searching the necessary keywords to retrieve such examples  as I was not able to find specific examples.

**Could someone please tell me of some specific examples of problems that were originally considered as NP and what lead them to be reclassified as P?**

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is fine, but technically the problems wouldn't be reclassified as P rather than NP. P is a subset of NP so the problems don't stop being in NP once they are shown to be in P.

Comment: Having had a quick look on Wikipedia (I haven't checked in depth) primality testing is a famous problem that was shown to be in NP in 1975 several years before it was shown to be in P in 2002.

Comment: thank you so much for your replies everyone!